# Retrieving queue depth using hermesJMS or shell script of WebSphere MQ

Tags: unix, admin, ibm-mq, instrumentation

I have `hermesJMS` setup and `soapUI`. I'd like a small script that can go in either via `hermesJMS` or another way to retrieve the queue depth of a particular queue.

Is there a way to do this easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The JMS specification does not provide an API for object inquiry, however IBM provides one using native Java classes and the C API using Programmable Command Formats, or PCF for short.  The PCF reference docs are [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/zr00120_.htm).

If you have installed the WMQ client code ([free download with registration](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71)) you will have the sample programs on your laptop.  By default, these reside in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\pcf\samples` for Windows or in `/opt/mqm/samp/` for UNIX/Linux.  Take a look at `PCF_ListQueueNames.java` for a starting point.  If you were to substitute `MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q` for `MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_NAMES` in that program you'd be very close to what you require.

Alternatively since you requested alternatives, you might look at [SupportPac MO72](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMO72).  This SupportPac can be used as a client version of `runmqsc` so that you can, from a central server, write scripts that query your entire WMQ network.  Of course, it also works in local bindings mode. Among the other features that make MO72 great for scripting is an option to format output to one line per object.  This lets you grep out the line of interest, then strip out the value of interest.